# Does damage dealt by Searing Blood's delayed trigger cause Satyr Firedancer to trigger?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I found [this unofficial ruling on Searing Blood](http://magicjudge.tumblr.com/post/116005374414/two-part-question-1-if-searing-blood-is-removed), but it doesn't make sense to me. To sum up the question and the answer (in case of link rot):

> Q: Does the damage dealt by [Searing Blood](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSearing%20Blood%5d)'s delayed trigger cause [Satyr Firedancer](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSatyr%20Firedancer%5d) to trigger?
>
> A: No. The damage is dealt by a delayed trigger, which is not an instant or sorcery.*

The delayed trigger clearly says that Searing Blood deals 3 damage. Searing Blood is an instant. Therefore, I think Satyr Firedancer should trigger. Can someone explain why Satyr Firedancer would or would not trigger?

This question was prompted by a [related one](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/23736/2880).

---

<sub>*
The judge reversed the ruling, but was kind enough to leave notes about it. Keep in mind that the paraphrased quote above reflects the original ruling.</sub>

Comment: It seems to me that the answer to your previous question should provide an answer to this question, one way or another.

Comment: Judges are not infallible....

Comment: @John I didn't claim judges were infallible. I just asked if the ruling is correct.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just emailed the judge and alerted her to the potential mistake, as politely as I am able. There's a possibility that this will prompt her to change the ruling, which means that we will have made the Internet a slightly better place. :)

Comment: I would hope that the existence of this question/answer pair would have already made the Internet a better place by clarifying the situation.

Comment: It looks like she has updated her answer, good job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The ruling is incorrect. The source of the damage is the Searing Blood spell. When Searing Blood resolves, it creates a delayed triggered ability

> When that creature dies this turn, Searing Blood deals 3 damage to the creature's controller.

The "Searing Blood" in the triggered ability refers to the spell Searing Blood, so when the triggered ability resolves, the spell is the source of the damage. Since the spell no longer exists, its last known information is used.

Answer (score 4):

If the source of the damage is a delayed triggered ability, then the ruling is right.

But the source of the damage is not a triggered ability; it's Searing Blood ("Searing Blood deals ..."), and Searing Blood is an instant. (Triggered abilities don't even have names.)

Or at least it was an instant when it last existed. Having since been moved to the graveyard, the object no longer exists (which is [perfectly fine](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/23736/2880)), so Last Known Information is used. When it last existed, it was an instant, so the damage was dealt by an instant.

Comment: Is it even possible for a triggered ability (or an ability in general) to be the source of damage?

Comment: @GendoIkari, In theory, it isn't against the rules (abilities on the stack are objects). In practice, I think it's a concept Wizards wants to avoid. I seem to remember there was an accidental occurrence of this that was fixed.